# Replicating data from SQL Server to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I've been trying to follow instructions from Google on Replicating data from SQL Server to BigQuery available here: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery.  Following instructions to the letter step by step always results in this odd error when creating the Cloud Fusion instance

```
Invalid argument (HTTP 400): retry budget exhausted (3 attempts): cloud-control2-saas::GCE_BAD_REQUEST: Invalid value for field 'networkPeering.name': '*******'. Must be a match of regex '(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'.
```

**** is the project ID with the VPC network suffix after a dash and it looks a bit like this (I've changed values)

website.com:api-project-0000000000-default

This value is being assigned somewhere by Google, I am not given a choice to select this or enter this through the instructions when creating the Instance.

Googling the error doesn't show me anything useful and sadly I do not have budget to acquire GCP support in this instance to try and ask them why their instruction appear not to work.

I've already checked quotas, billing, service account permissions, etc.  I've also tried both a new VPC as well as a shared VPC with all the settings from the guide.

Would appreciate someone more experienced in this area maybe point me in the right direction or if someone has some sort of understanding of where else to check what could be wrong I would appreciate it.

Instructions do point at creating a peering connection but the instructions themselves require the Cloud Data Fusion Instance to be created before configuring the peering connection and since I can't create the Cloud Data Fusion Instance I am unsure on what exactly I am supposed to do.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Could you mention what is the length of `networkPeering.name`?

Comment: The project ID as referenced in the error code has 46 characters in total.  Formatting is exactly as displayed 'ourwebsitename.com', then ':', then 'api-project-' then '10 numbers from 0 to 9' and last is what I am guessing the VPC it is using '-default' since it is the only "default" named resource on our GCP.

Comment: Apologies for the ignorance but when I click on your "private thread" link it is asking me for some Google credentials I do not have.  Have I misunderstood your instructions?

Comment: Hi, GCP support here. Can you raise a [private thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=716142&template=1328477) in the issue tracker referencing this question, as stated in the template with the project ID, picture of the error trace and reproduction steps? After you've created the thread, please share here the issue ID so we can follow up. Note that issues in that component will only be accessible for you and GCP support.

Comment: Thank you for the updated link.  Issue ID: 218266803

Comment: Thank you but it wasn't helpful at all.  The suggested answer was to change the project ID (which cannot be done) so essentially to create a brand new project or move to another project and I don't feel that is a good resolution as we have a lot of resources in the project that would need to be shifted as well).  This is obviously a bug, since we have no control over the peering network name nor the project ID after its been generated, so I think you guys need to have some sort of alias to reference the resources better instead of relying on something we can't change and wont always work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/create-private-ip), before creating a private instance I assume you're creating a VPC network.

`networkPeering.name` is a combination of your Project-id and VPC-network. The error which you're getting is due to incorrect naming convention of networkPeeering name. ie. the value of networkPeering.name does not match the regex expression `(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)`, which in your case is due to the project-ID: website.com:api-project-xxxxxxxxx.

Also note that networkPeering name should be less than 63 characters in length as per the regex expression.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but as explained above the entire name has 46 characters (below the limit) and I have no access to change that since it is an immutable value.  I am also not offered to enter a network peering name, this is automatically inferred (as you also realized) so I can't really control that.  I can change the network name but as mentioned also in my original post, I have tried with the both a shared vpc and a new vpc where I've personalized the name.  Even the current one "default" doesn't have anything odd that would prevent it from working.

Comment: I tried creating a private Data Fusion instance as per the documentation in a new VPC but encountered no such error. It appears that this issue has to be further investigated internally.

Comment: We tested on another project / account and we were able to get it working there but the error is persistent on the one where we actually need it.  It does seem like the project ID is the culprit but the project ID is NOT a value I can control as far as I am aware after creation.  So perhaps could be looked at.  I'll open an issue.  Thanks!